# Order by multiple column in mongodb laravel

Tags: php, mongodb, sorting, laravel, sql-order-by

I have a query. I want to sort a table using two columns. I am using mongodb laravel jessengers library for using laravel eloquent .

this is my query:

```
 Publish::with(array('user','notify','notify.user','hoots','story','image'))
         ->whereIn('user_id',$key_with_current_user)
         ->orwhereIn('post_id',$news_data)          
         ->orderBy('score','DESC')  
         ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')          
         ->get()
         ->toArray();
```

Now result i am getting is by column specified first. for above query it is sorted by score but not by score and created_at.

Any help? how can we sort by multiple column in mongodb using laravel eloquent queries.

I have also tested this in rockmongo's query shell and it behave same. Only get sorted by one column.

For test i have data like

```
 {
 "_id": ObjectId("54abd1888ead0ee85f8b4569"),
 "created_at": ISODate("2015-01-06T12:14:00.819Z"),
 "post_id": "54abd1888ead0ee85f8b4568",
 "score": NumberInt(0),   
 "updated_at"▼: ISODate("2015-01-07T15:43:27.28Z"),
}
{
"_id": ObjectId("54ad2bf98ead0e22658b4569"),
"created_at": ISODate("2015-01-07T12:52:09.81Z"),
"post_id": "54ad2bf98ead0e22658b4568",
"score": 0.22106,  
"updated_at": ISODate("2015-01-07T14:20:53.942Z")
}
{
"_id": ObjectId("54accd868ead0e826a8b456a"),
"created_at": ISODate("2015-01-07T06:09:10.920Z"),
"post_id": "54accd868ead0e826a8b4569",
"score": 2.83313,   
"updated_at": ISODate("2015-01-07T08:42:22.116Z")
```

}

Comment: Not answering because laravel is "not my bag" (colloq: Not in my experience ), but can you not just supply an array as a literal MongoDB construct? ie: `->orderBy(array( 'score' => -1, 'created_at' => -1 ))`. Or does that blow up the method with an error? Commenting because I'm not testing or knowing, just thinking logically. To me at least. I'm probably wrong.

Comment: thanks for your response . throws an error Illegal offset type.

Comment: Okay, understood. It throws an error. Worth a shot though. There surely must be a logical way if "chaining" calls does not work as well though. It would not be built to only sort on one field. There must be another syntax. Try looking at the unit tests in the source code.

Comment: yes thank you . i am looking into it. let you know if it works

Comment: @AnilSharma have you found something?